# Group By dynamic list with Count

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using a simple case statement to count the occurrences of breakcode in my data and grouping by Seller and SaleDate.

However it seems like an inelegant solution. The breakcode could and quite possibly will expand and I would need to update my code when it does. How can this be done?

Additionally, while using NULL gives me the right answers, I would like to know is there a better approach to how I am counting my instances of breakcode, putting 0 in place of NULL returns the incorrect results?

```
SELECT seller, 
saledate,
COUNT(CASE WHEN breakcode = 1 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as [Perfect],
COUNT(CASE WHEN breakcode = 2 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as [Simple],
COUNT(CASE WHEN breakcode = 3 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as [Medium],
COUNT(CASE WHEN breakcode = 4 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as [Dual1],
COUNT(CASE WHEN breakcode = 5 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as [Dual2],
COUNT(CASE WHEN breakcode = 6 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as [Hard],
COUNT(CASE WHEN breakcode = 7 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as [Difficult]
FROM test
GROUP BY seller, sale date
```

Thanks.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26f6d/2

Comment: Do you have "somewhere" that `breakcode=1` means `Perfect`?  If not, then you'll wind up with columns named `1` using dynamic sql.

Comment: 'Breakcode' is an id for 'breakname' which is held in another table. I have tried simplifying here.

Comment: Including that would make it much easier to answer because the code will be different.

Answer (score 2):

Final version developed through comments:

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols= ISNULL(@cols + ',','') + QUOTENAME(case when breakname like 'Perfect%' then 'Perfect' else breakname end)
FROM (select * from breaks where breakname not like 'Perfect - 90') a
group by id, breakname
order by id


SET @sql =
  N'SELECT seller, saledate, ' + @cols + '
    FROM (select seller, saledate, case when breakname like ''Perfect%'' then ''Perfect'' else breakname end breakname from test 
    inner join breaks on case when breakcode = 8 then 1 else breakcode end = id) derived
    PIVOT(count(breakname)
          FOR derived.breakname IN (' + @cols + ')) AS PVTTable
        ORDER BY seller, saledate'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/%23!3/05d6da/3)

Comment: `Breakcode` is an id for `breakname` which itself is held in another table `Breaks`. I have tried simplifying here. Ultimately, I want to group by `like Perfect%` or like other break names.

Comment: @user1773949 Simplifying your actual problem isn't the best way to get a solution. You should include all the needed details to properly answer it.

Comment: @bluefeet ok, let me quickly get a new fiddle created. JPW's answer is correct but in place of the column header numbers I would like the break name. One moment...

Comment: @bluefeet How can I change the order of the headers to match the id order and not text order in the fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/37748/1 ? Can't seem to change it. That is the order of the items in the IN in the PIVOT

Comment: @jpw you have to use `group by` and `order by` instead of `distinct` -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/37748/5

Comment: @jpw You can simplify the code even more -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e0ac/1 - I'd guess they'd want to return all `codename` values - so you don't need the join when getting the list of columns.

Comment: @bluefeet Yeah that certainly looks better; had a feeling the derived table was not needed, but it was already in the template I used as source. Good to know; better update the template.

Comment: @user1773949 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eb9a4b/5 this is your query adapted to dynamic pivot

Comment: @bluefeet,@jpw thanks, this is almost exactly what I am looking for. It's a very nice solution. I have one more addition. Let's say I want to count all of the 'Perfects' under one column which means I would need to use `like Perfect%`, is this possible?  So combining the 3 + 1 in the top row here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05d6da/1

Comment: @user1773949 Try this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05d6da/3 it's really ugly with hard coded values to change Perfect90 to Perfect.

Comment: @jpw, less uglier than my initial approach. Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I need. Do you want to change your actual answer above to this so I can accept it?